# Java synchronized block, not all the threads get terminated

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have the following code:

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.lang.Integer;

class MyThread extends Thread {
private int id;

MyThread(int i){
    id = i;
    }

public void run() {
    while(true){
        try{                    
            synchronized(Global.lock){
                Global.lock.wait();
                if(Global.n == 0) {System.out.println(id); Global.lock.notify(); break;}
                --Global.n;
                System.out.println("I am thread " + id + "\tn is now " + Global.n);
                Global.lock.notify();
                }
            }
        catch(Exception e){break;}
        }
    }
}

class Global{
public static int n;
public static Object lock = new Object();
}

public class Sync2{
public static final void main(String[] sArgs){
    int threadNum = Integer.parseInt(sArgs[0]);
    Global.n = Integer.parseInt(sArgs[1]);

    MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[threadNum];

    for(int i = 0; i < threadNum; ++i){
        threads[i] = new MyThread(i);
        threads[i].start();     
        }
    synchronized(Global.lock){Global.lock.notify();}
}
}
```

two parameters are entered: a number `n` and the number of threads to be created. Every thread decreases n by one and then passes control. All threads should stop when n is 0. It seems to work fine so far, but the only problem is that in most of the cases all threads except one terminate. And one is hanging on. Any idea why?

And yes, this is part of a homework, and that is what I've done so far (I was no provided with the code). I'am also explicitly restricted to use a synchronized block and only `wait()` and `.notify()` methods by the task.

**EDIT:** modified the synchronized block a bit:

```
synchronized(Global.lock){
  Global.lock.notify();
  if (Global.n == 0) {break;}
  if (Global.next != id) {Global.lock.wait();  continue;}
  --Global.n;
  System.out.println("I am thread " + id + "\tn is now " + Global.n);
  Global.next = ++Global.next % Global.threadNum;
  }
```

now threads act strictly in the order they are created. Its pretty unclear from the task wording, but might be the right thing.

Comment: Your lock object should be `final`.

Comment: Do you have to use `wait` and `notify` or are they optional?  If all you're trying to do is decrement n you could do it with just `synchronized`.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Seems to me like I actually have to... Still can't figure out a way to make it work for a single worker. Actually there is nobody to notify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition. Think about what happens with a single worker thread. `Global.n` is set to 1 and then the thread starts. It immediately goes into a wait state. Suppose, though, that `notify()` had already been called on the main thread. Since the worker thread hasn't yet entered a wait state, it isn't notified. Then, when it finally does call `wait()`, there are no other threads around to call `notify()`, it stays in the wait state forever. You need to fix up your logic to avoid this race condition.

Also, do you really want a single worker thread to decrement `Global.n` more than once? That can easily happen with your `while (true) ...` loop.

**EDIT**
You also have another logic problem with a single thread. Suppose it enters the wait state and then the `notify()` in `main` is called. It wakes the worker thread which decrements `Global.n` to 0, calls `notify()`, and then goes back to waiting. The problem is that `notify()` didn't wake any other thread because there were no other threads to wake. So the one worker thread will wait forever. I haven't analyzed it fully, but something like this might also happen with more than one worker thread.

Comment: Hmmm...I think I liked your original answer better.  Who is going to wake the last thread?  If he puts a timeout in `Global.lock.wait();` his program will end.  For example, replacing his original wait with `Global.lock.wait(5000);` will make his program end 5 seconds after the count becomes 0.

Comment: Yes, if I have a single worker, it should decrement n n times. And I'm not allowed to use wait() with parameters.

Comment: @Paul - When the penultimate worker thread notices that `Global.n==0`, it will call `notify()` just before it exits. That ought to wake the last thread, which will also then exit.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have a naked wait() call, as semaphores in java are not cached. wait() should always be nested in some sort of

```
while (condition that you are waiting on)
    obj.wait();
```

Comment: Where does OP have a naked `wait()` call?

Comment: ok, well i don't think an `if` is fully clothed. because you could be woken up, only to find that the condition isn't set. but since you're not in a while, you plow forward mistakenly.

Comment: also: `synchronized(Global.lock){
                Global.lock.wait();` is totally naked

Comment: how does that possibly matter. the while loop is outside the synchronized block.